# Change Shape of Heatmap Element from Circle to Square？

Tags: openlayers-6

I'm a novice in Openlayer6. Who can tell me how to change the rendered elements of the Heatmap.js from a circle to a square? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not configurable, though you can override the createRenderer method of the Heatmap layer to do this (not supported by the api, so it may break in the future).

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/heatmap-earthquakes-squares-hdrbs?file=/main.js

These are the needed changes from the orignal function:

```
diff --git a/src/ol/layer/Heatmap.js b/src/ol/layer/Heatmap.js
index c3e3306c8..2873bf184 100644
--- a/src/ol/layer/Heatmap.js
+++ b/src/ol/layer/Heatmap.js
@@ -222,8 +222,8 @@ class Heatmap extends VectorLayer {
 
         void main(void) {
           vec2 texCoord = v_texCoord * 2.0 - vec2(1.0, 1.0);
-          float sqRadius = texCoord.x * texCoord.x + texCoord.y * texCoord.y;
-          float value = (1.0 - sqrt(sqRadius)) * u_blurSlope;
+          float distance = max(abs(texCoord.x), abs(texCoord.y));
+          float value = (1.0 - distance) * u_blurSlope;
           float alpha = smoothstep(0.0, 1.0, value) * v_weight;
           gl_FragColor = vec4(alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha);
         }`,
@@ -263,8 +263,8 @@ class Heatmap extends VectorLayer {
 
         void main(void) {
           vec2 texCoord = v_texCoord * 2.0 - vec2(1.0, 1.0);
-          float sqRadius = texCoord.x * texCoord.x + texCoord.y * texCoord.y;
-          float value = (1.0 - sqrt(sqRadius)) * u_blurSlope;
+          float distance = max(abs(texCoord.x), abs(texCoord.y));
+          float value = (1.0 - distance) * u_blurSlope;
           float alpha = smoothstep(0.0, 1.0, value) * v_weight;
           if (alpha < 0.05) {
             discard;
```